# Can I play "Brunswick Pro Bowling" without Kinect?

Tags: kinect, brunswick-pro-bowling

Can I play "Brunswick Pro Bowling" without Kinect, with only a wireless controller on the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. The vast majority of games that use Kinect require it in order to play the game. I only know of one game that supports both the normal controller and Kinect - Child of Eden.

Answer (score 5):

If the cover says "Requires Kinect Sensor" with a purple sticker, as Brunswick Pro Bowling does ([see here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0037TPGJG)) then you need the Kinect to play.

Child of Eden on the other hand, simply says "Better with kinect sensor" in sort of a "notification bar" style artwork ([see here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I0H8FK)), as such the Kinect is optional.